# Ctags langmap files with multiple extensions

Tags: ctags, exuberant-ctags

In our codebase we have some files that are generated by a python script, so they are named `cpp_filename.cpp.py`, `java_filename.j.py`, etc. I have setup my ctags to map .cpp files to C++ and .j files to Java, however I can't figure out how to set it up to map `.cpp.py` files to C++ and `.j.py` files to Java. If I try to map just `.py` files to C++, it will also map the `.j.py` file which I don't want to happen obviously. Is this something I can do with ctags, or is ctags limited in its ability to only look at the last file extension? I am using ctags 5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Universal ctags, an unofficial fork of Exuberant ctags, the following command line may help you:

```
$  ctags --options=NONE  --map-Python=-.py --map-Java=+'(*.j.py)' --map-C++=+'(*.cpp.py)' --print-language foo.j.py  ...
```

You can verify the language choice in Universal ctag with the `--print-language` option:

```
$ touch foo.j.py foo.cpp.py
$ ctags --print-language foo.j.py foo.cpp.py
foo.j.py: Python
foo.cpp.py: Python
$ ctags --map-Python=-.py --map-Java=+'(*.j.py)' --map-C++=+'(*.cpp.py)' --print-language foo.j.py foo.cpp.py
foo.j.py: Java
foo.cpp.py: C++
```

With Exuberant ctags, I cannot find a solution.

I expected  `ctags --options=NONE  --map-Python=-.py --map-Java=+'.j.py' --map-C++=+'.cpp.py' --print-language foo.j.py foo.cpp.py` works expectedly. However, it doesn't work well. It may be a bug of Universal ctags.